# Flutter Post Request

Tags: api, flutter, dart

I need to write Post request with header and json body, as the following;

## Header Request:

```
Content-Type:application/json

Authorization:Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzUxMiJ9
```

## Body Request:

```
{
  "Data": {
    "Permissions": [
      "ReadAccountsDetail",
      "ReadProducts",
      "ReadStandingOrdersDetail",
      "ReadTransactionsCredits",
      "ReadTransactionsDebits",
      "ReadTransactionsDetail",
      "ReadPAN"
    ],
    "ExpirationDateTime": "2019-06-29T00:00:00+00:00",
    "TransactionFromDateTime": "2019-05-03T00:00:00+00:00",
    "TransactionToDateTime": "2019-12-03T00:00:00+00:00"
  },
  "Risk": {}
}
```

Comment: Use the http package: https://pub.dev/packages/http

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Sergio Bernal pointed out, you should include `http` in your pubspec.yaml:

```
dependencies:
    ...
    http: any
```

Then import it like following:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
```

Which will allow you to use the following method:

```
http.post(dynamic url, {Map<String, String> headers, dynamic body, Encoding encoding})
```

Here's your example:

```
String url = "http://example.co"
Map<String, String> headers = new Map<String, String>();
headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzUxMiJ9';
headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';

String body = jsonEncode(
    {
        "Data": {
            "Permissions": [
            "ReadAccountsDetail",
            "ReadProducts",
            "ReadStandingOrdersDetail",
            "ReadTransactionsCredits",
            "ReadTransactionsDebits",
            "ReadTransactionsDetail",
            "ReadPAN"
            ],
            "ExpirationDateTime": "2019-06-29T00:00:00+00:00",
            "TransactionFromDateTime": "2019-05-03T00:00:00+00:00",
            "TransactionToDateTime": "2019-12-03T00:00:00+00:00"
          },
       "Risk": {}
    }
);

await http.post(url, headers: headers, body: body).then((response){
    if(response.statusCode == 200) {
        //Success
    } else {
        //Handle failure
    }
});
```

Comment: hi mertcanb, thanks for the code, but i have problem with the body, it is in json format and i saw few example that they are using map. could you please help me in this as will. or should i just copy it there?

Comment: You can add your JSON object inside the `jsonEncode` method and send the request with the body string. See edited answer!